# Using Tex to typeset a cryptogram

Tags: tex-core

I want to create a Tex file to create something like the image below. Basically a letter underneath a cell.

I don't really want to use a table. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76264129/using-tex-to-typeset-a-cryptogram

Comment: Welcome. // Why TeX only?

Comment: I'm a GOM. This is not a "do it for me" site. Provide an MWE showing what you have tried and exhibiting your problem. For all we know your code might consist of something like \crypt{\stuff}. If you need help you have to help potential helpers

Comment: I have no idea what a GOM is. I've done nothing, there is no MWE, since I didn't even know where to begin. How could I do a MWE? In fact, I didn't even know it was possible until a helpful person answered.

Comment: @MS-SPO I have been using tex recently for another program where I needed to output to a PDF, and build it up from a sequence of data generated by a program. I thought it might be possible to do in TEX, but I tried things like cwpuzzle and it didn't work.

Comment: @RickDearman Peter is a Grumpy Old Man.

Comment: Your attempt with cwpuzzle would have been a nice MWE.

Comment: @Teepeemm, that is true, however I knew from that attempt that cwpuzzle was something I didn't want to use, and would prefer something else.

Comment: GOM = "GRUMPY OLD MAN" It is nothing personal about you, but about me. It would be a really good idea for you to.look at your queston as you asked it and decide if there was enough information provided to help you resolve it. I think that your question is along the lines of "I baked a cake but it was inedible. Please help" \i see no reason why I should spend my precious time I helipnd based on rthe inpi=ut btou have provided.

Answer (score 12):

For example, using OpTeX, the TeX file may look like this:

```
\def\cryptogram#1{\def\tmp{#1}\let\cryptotext=\tmp \replstring\tmp{ }{{ }}%
   \par\noindent
   \ea\foreach\tmp\do{\ea\ifx\space##1\kern1em \else \boxit{##1}{}\fi}%
   \par
}
\def\boxit#1#2{\vbox{
   \hbox to1em{\hss\frame{\hbox to.6em{\lower.4ex\vbox to1em{}\hss#2\hss}}\hss}
   \hbox to1em{\hss #1\hss}
}}
\def\solution#1{\def\tmp{#1}\replstring\tmp{ }{{ }}%
   \par\noindent
   \ea\foreach\tmp\do{\ea\ifx\space##1\kern1em \else \boxit{\ea\crypto\cryptotext\end}{##1}\fi}%
   \par
}
\def\crypto#1#2\end{#1\gdef\cryptotext{#2}}

\cryptogram{TGIAB FZU TGPHVGHPB}
\bigskip

\solution{MAYBE THE SOLUTION.}

\bye
```

The result looks like this:

[image: crypto]

Comment: That is brilliant! I never heard of OpTeX before, so I'll have to do some reading up. A followup question (hopefully allowed) How would I print the solution? e.g. all the correct letters inside the boxes?

Comment: OK, I added the "solution" part of the macros.

Comment: You're a STAR! Thanks a million.